# Trying to scan a UPS Maxicode without losing invisible special characters

Tags: html, forms, scanning

**I have the following task:** Allow to scan a UPS Maxicode into a webform and parse using PHP.
My Equipment is a USB-Connected 2D Imager "Motorola Symbol DS3508" detected as "Keyboard"-replacement.

**My problem:** If I scan a maxicode into a HTML webform (text or textarea) the special hidden characters   and  are dropped. If - on the opposite - I scan the maxicode into Notepad++ with the same scanner and unchanged settings, they are retained. Attempting to copy the string from Notepad++ into the same html webform and submit with post works fine, the special characters are retained and can be detected / parsed with PHP.

**Question:** What do I have to do to have a HTML webform retain those special characters during the imager scan already without having to scan into Notepad++ first, then copy/paste into the webform?

Any idea is much appreciated.

Here's my php / html code sniplet

```
<?php 
if (!isset($_POST['maxicode']))
{ ?>
    <form action="<?echo $self;?>" method="post">
        <input type="textarea" charset="UTF-8" name="maxicode" placeholder="Scan Maxicode here" required />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
<? } 
else {
    //$maxicode="[)>01960680  5780661Z58416520UPSN8DDD5E0421/15NOSLO";
    $maxicode=$_POST['maxicode'];
    echo $maxicode."<br>";
    $mc=explode ("", $maxicode);
    print_r($mc);
} ?>
```

As an example: Here's how the scan looks like in Notepad++
[image: Scan code]

Comment: Could you give us an example on how a properly formatted Maxicode would look like?

Comment: It's hard to show here due to the fact that the maxicode does have invisible characters dividing the data fields. The screenshot http://i.stack.imgur.com/7HmqX.jpg does show a properly formatted maxicode as it's readable in Notepad++. The non-printable characters contained in the data string are:
• [)>Rs is the message header
• Gs is used to separate fields in a message (decimal 29)
• Rs is used to separate format types (decimal 30)
• Fs is used to separate the primary and secondary address numbers (decimal 28)
• Eot is the end of transmission character (decimal 4)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that non printable characters cannot be transmitted unencoded in the POST request. The solution would be to use JavaScript to encode the string containing the non printable characters before the form is transmitted, then decode it again once it reaches the serever.

Something like this

```
// Catch that the form is being submitted
var codeInput = document.getElementById("codeInput");
var unescapedCode = codeInput.value;

// Replace content with replaced text
codeInput.innerHTML = encodeURIComponent(unescapedCode);
```

I made an example [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OPXEPv). I inserted the non printable characters in the string with a hex editor.

Then all you have to do is decode it again on the server (example using PHP).

```
$code = urldecode($_POST["codeInput"]);
```

This should now contain the non printable characters.